# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in `TextInput`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the error which shows on my google chrome browser console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in
> `TextInput`, but its value is `undefined`.

Here's the code:

**text-input.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TextInput = (props) => (
<div className="form-group">
    <label htmlFor={props.name}>{props.label}</label>
    <input 
        className="form-control mb-2"
        type={props.type}
        name={props.name}
        id={props.name}
        value={props.value}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        onChange={props.onChange}
    />
</div>
);

TextInput.propTypes = {
type: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
placeholder: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

TextInput.defaultProps = {
type:'text',
placeholder: '',
}

export default TextInput;
```

**form.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import TextInput from './text-input';

const Form = (props) => (
<form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
    <TextInput
        name="name"
        value={props.values.name}
        label="Enter Name"
        placeholder="Enter Your Name"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
    />
    <TextInput
        type="email"
        name="email"
        value={props.values.eamil}
        label="Enter Email"
        placeholder="Enter Your Email"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
    />
    <TextInput
        type="password"
        name="password"
        value={props.values.password}
        label="Enter Password"
        placeholder="Enter Your password"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
    />
    <button className="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
);

Form.propTypes = {
values: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Form;
```

Where is the problem and How can I find out the problem?

Comment: Please show where you are rendering `Form` when this error message occurs. It looks like its `values` prop is missing a value for one or more of the `name`, `email` and `password` properties.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely case is that your `props.value.name` etc are originally `undefined`. In that case, you are passing `undefined` as the `value` prop to your `TextInput` component, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

This line has a typo on the email prop:

```
 value={props.values.eamil}
```

should be

```
  value={props.values.email}
```